# Is there any relation between Courant Fischer's minmax theorem, Principle Component Analysis and Total Variation on Graphs?

Tags: signal-processing, linear-algebra, graph-theory

Does Courant Fischer' minmax theorem applied on to the Graph Laplacian colligate with the total variation in graph signals? Are these related to Principle Component Analysis on the Graphs? Because all of there terminologies deal with the arrangement of eigenvalues (derived from the Laplacian matrix) in ascending order from 0 to lambda max.

Please provide a deeper insights by comparing them side-by-side.

I am looking for a thorough elaboration of the three aforementioned terms and if these terms on a graph are all interlinked/correlated.